# PXN-0082 controller - xinput does not see but lsusb does - how to connect

Tags: usb-device, xinput, input-method, lsusb

I have an arcade controller I bought so my dying dad can play old school games.

but it does not show up under xinput, where it does show up under lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 021: ID 0079:187c DragonRise Inc. FightStick
```

I've tried

```
xinput --reattached 0079:187c {various things}
```

but that ID is not in xinput's list.

my system is:

```
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
Kernel: 5.10.70-1-MANJARO
Shell: bash 5.1.8
```

so my question is: how do I get this device working?

or - how do I force a device to be visible to xinput? (if I know it should be)

Comment: random search on Internet using `DragonRise Inc. FightStick "linux"`: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/8qp5xn/my_gamepadarcade_stick_not_work_only_in_linux/ . If that works for you, please write an answer with the steps you had to do.

Comment: "lsusb sees it, xinput doesn't" -> usb level works, X driver doesn't pick it up. Check if it's visible on the kernel event input layer (edit question with new lines in `dmesg` after you plug it in). If `dmesg` doesn't show an event input driver picking it up, you need a driver.

Comment: thank you! will try these things tonight!

Answer (score 1):

okay, thanks to the comments here: got it sorted and working:

first things first need python-pip

then needed to sort out the xboxdrv package:

Clone this repo

Open the PKGBUILD

then make two changes: in the makedepends and build(){}

```
CHANGE:
makedepends=( 'scons' 'boost' 'pkg-config' 'libx11' 'python')
INTO:
makedepends=( 'boost' 'pkg-config' 'libx11' 'python')


AND


CHANGE:
build() {
  cd ${pkgname}-${pkgver}
 scons \

build() {
  cd ${pkgname}-${pkgver}
  python3 ~/.local/bin/scons \
```

Then make sure the python dependency is installed:

```
    pip install 'scons==4.1'
```

whoot, xboxdrv now installs properly with

```
makepgk -si
```

now that's installed: we need to make modprobe not see xpad: by blacklisting:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

( it errors if you don't blacklist xpad)

then insert the following:

```
blacklist xpad
```

once that's done we can force xboxdrv to use device by ID.

```
lsusb 

Bus 005 Device 009: ID **0079:187c** DragonRise Inc
```

(the device id: was identical to the reddit post from 3 years ago)

now do the magic

```
xboxdrv --type xbox360 --device-by-id 0079:187c &
```

optimizations are how to make it so this command automatically runs when it detects the device connecting: but I'm happy being able to have this command in a script to start the emulator as well after :) bin that call it emulator or whatever and call it a day.

thank you for the help.